# Pausar a exibição de uma função

Tags: javascript, html5

Fiz um programa para ser meio que um cronômetro depois de se apertar o botão de play, porém não consigo pensar em uma lógica de quando eu apertar o botão de pause o contador pausar a mostragem dos números onde ele estiver (sem zerar os números já mostrados) e depois, se o botão play fosse pressionado novamente a contagem continuaria de onde pausou.

Código até agora:

```
<body>
    <div id="number"></div>
    <button class="play" onclick="play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
    <script>
        var seg = 0;
        var min = 0;
        var l = document.getElementById("number");
        function play() {
            window.setInterval(function() {
                if (seg < 10) {
                    l.innerHTML = '0' + min + ':' + '0' + seg;
                    seg++;
                } else {
                    l.innerHTML = '0' + min + ':' + seg;
                    seg++;
                }
                if (seg > 60) {
                    seg = 0;
                    min++;
                    if (seg < 10) {
                    l.innerHTML = '0' + min + ':' + '0' + seg;
                    seg++;
                } else {
                    l.innerHTML = '0' + min + ':' + seg;
                    seg++;
                }
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        function pause() {
            
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Já viu o `clearInterval`? Tem exemplos na [documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo voce pode olhar o clearInterval conforme o Rafel Tavares falou

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#examples

Ou algo bem simples como uma variavel:

```
    <body>
    <div id="number"></div>
    <button class="play" onclick="play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
    <script>
        var seg = 0;
        var min = 0;
        var l = document.getElementById("number");
        var isPause = false;
        function play() {
            window.setInterval(function() {
                if(!isPause){
                if (seg < 10) {
                    l.innerHTML = '0' + min + ':' + '0' + seg;
                    seg++;
                } else {
                    l.innerHTML = '0' + min + ':' + seg;
                    seg++;
                }
                if (seg > 60) {
                    seg = 0;
                    min++;
                    if (seg < 10) {
                    l.innerHTML = '0' + min + ':' + '0' + seg;
                    seg++;
                } else {
                    l.innerHTML = '0' + min + ':' + seg;
                    seg++;
                }
                }
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        function pause() {
            isPause = true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```